# Font-awesome icons not showing but main.css is showing

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I have a project with bootstrap en font-awesome setup if I view my main.css the first thing I see is that font-awesome is imported. And all its icons, I don't understand why the html is not picking up the font-awesome classes.

```
/*!
 *  Font Awesome 4.4.0 by @davegandy - http://fontawesome.io - @fontawesome
 *  License - http://fontawesome.io/license (Font: SIL OFL 1.1, CSS: MIT License)
 */
/* FONT PATH
 * -------------------------- */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');
  src: url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') format('woff2'), url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') format('woff'), url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') format('truetype'), url('../../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
.fa {
  display: inline-block;
  font: normal normal normal 14px/1 FontAwesome;
  font-size: inherit;
  text-rendering: auto;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

I'll hope someone can help me out on this

Comment: if the cont is not showing. Are you looking in the correct folder? in your `@font-face`

Comment: Try to check in the developer tools network tab if all font awesome files `(eot, woff2, woff, ttf and svg)` can be loaded or if one or more cannot loaded from the browser.

Comment: You could always use the font awesome CDN - https://cdn.fontawesome.com/

Comment: Indeed the eot, woff2 etc arent loaded. But where do I load these in an bootstrap project?

Comment: Is that in the font-awesome.less file?

Comment: Is there a error in the network tab like `not found`? Or simply the file not getting loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is this your project folder looks like?
[folder structure image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by4NF.jpg)

if so, then remove one "../" in your font-awesome.css file.

```
 @font-face {
  font-family: 'FontAwesome';
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?v=4.4.0');
  src: url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.eot?#iefix&v=4.4.0') format('embedded-opentype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff2?v=4.4.0') format('woff2'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.4.0') format('woff'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.4.0') format('truetype'), url('../fonts/fontawesome-webfont.svg?v=4.4.0#fontawesomeregular') format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the font path, check in the Console of your browser (Ctrl+Shift+J on Chrome) if you don't get an alert like

> Failed to load resource: [...]

This kind of warning means that the path of the ressource is wrong.